# Playing an Undine Druid with the water domain, can I use water affinity for domain spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class, druid

Let me preface this with this is my first character, and I have no idea what I'm doing.

Water affinity gives water domain powers and spells at +1 caster level to undine clerics.
I'm thinking because I'm a druid, having the ability won't do anything for me.

Am I right in this assumption?

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-undine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RAW, No.

Even if you take the water domain with your Nature Bond ability, Water Affinity specifically states "Undine clerics with the Water domain".

As a GM, I would completely allow it to affect your druid's domain spells.

Comment: Update: He said no